# List view items doesn't delete from SQLite database via custom adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, custom-adapter

Have a custom adapter that takes data from a database and displays via a listview.

My current code will 'delete' the row and refresh the adapter to show it has been deleted but on reload of the page it pulls the database from the database as it hasn't deleted it.

Please advise!!

Adapter class:

```
    public class FoodListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<FoodListItems> foodList;
    DatabaseCommands sqlHandler;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ItemDatabase dbHelper;
    private final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
    private final String TABLE_NAME = "foodItems";
    private final String DATABASE_NAME = "ItemDatabase.sqlite";
    private final int DATABASE_VERSION = 12;
    long id;

    public FoodListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FoodListItems> list) {

        this.context = context;
        foodList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return foodList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return foodList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

        FoodListItems FoodListItems = foodList.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_custom, null);

        }

        final ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.deleteItem);
        deleteButton.setTag(position);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                foodList.remove(position);
                System.out.println(position);
                dbHelper = new ItemDatabase(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,
                        DATABASE_VERSION);
                db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + " ="
                        + deleteButton.getTag(position), null);
                db.close();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        TextView itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        itemTitle.setText(FoodListItems.getTitle());
        TextView itemQuantity = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.itemQuantity);
        itemQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(FoodListItems.getQuantity()));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I think I need to get the listview row's corresponding database ID but I don't know how.

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is id value at this `deleteButton.setTag(id);` position? debug it and print into logcat

Comment: you can set the tag as follow: deleteButton.setTag(position); it will delete for sure.

Comment: The value returns as 0, but im now sure how to solve this problem :/

Comment: @KishanDhamat I have tried that but it still doesn't delete from database. System.out.println(deleteButton.getTag()) always returns 0 :/

Comment: put your code and edit it.

Comment: The output of tag is the row position in the list view (e.g. 1st list view = 0, 2nd = 1) however it does not delete from the database as the database row ID is incremented for each row.

Comment: clean your project, uninstall app. and then run.

Comment: Have tried. Item is still in the database i think as it still loads on page refresh :/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + " = " + (position+1), null);
```

and you haven't specified and id value, so set unique id on the delete button tag, or you can set position as a tag.

Comment: That code doesn't delete it from the database and on page refresh item is still there as it hasn't been removed from the Database.

Comment: have you set the tag properly?

Comment: please check the above code, i assume that is correct?

Comment: so when you are entering the data in the db at that time what are you inserting in the db in this COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID parameter?

Comment: COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null, that is how that column is made, auto increment with each row that is added

Comment: see new edit of code if its work then ok, otherwise i cant help you.

Comment: That didn't work :'(

it works if only 1 row in listview otherwise it doesn't work as database ID changes each time but listview position changes as items are removed